# Can we expand $(1-x)^{-1}$ for $\left| x\right| >1$

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series, formal-power-series

I don't know too much  about formal power series, but by using some common sense
I can say that
$$(1-x)^{-1}=1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4\ldots$$  will only hold iff $\left| x\right| <1$.
Does this series hold iff $\left| x\right| >1$?,\
But controversy is seen in "chapter 9 Renormalization" in Ryder's book on QFT at page 341, its as follows,
$$\begin{align}
D_{\mu\nu}'=D_{\mu\nu}-D_{\mu\alpha}\big(k^\alpha k^\beta-g^{\alpha\beta}k^2\big)\Pi(k^2)D_{\beta\nu}
\end{align}$$
and hence putting $D_{\mu\nu}=-g_{\mu\nu}/k^2,$
$$\begin{align}
D'_{\mu\nu}(k)&=\frac{1}{k^2[1+\Pi(k^2)]}\Bigg(-g_{\mu\nu}-\frac{k_\mu k_\nu}{k^2}\Pi(k^2)\Bigg)\\&=\frac{-g_{\mu\nu}}{k^2[1+\Pi(k^2)]} + \text{gauge terms}.  
\end{align}\tag{9.122}$$...
I tried a lot to attain his final formulae, Finally, I find that,
if $\Pi(k^2)$ is possible to expand as a power series, then I get the desired result,
So I expand
$$(1+\Pi(k^2))^{-1}=1+\Pi(k^2)+(\Pi(k^2))^2+\ldots$$ then I get the result given by Ryder by simple algebraic expansion as follows,
putting $D_{\mu\nu}=-\frac{g_{\mu\nu}}{k^2}$(Feynman's propagator)    gives
$$\begin{align}
D'_{\mu\nu}(k)=\frac{-g_{\mu\nu}}{k^2}-\Bigg(\frac{k_\mu k^\nu}{k^2}-g_{\mu\nu}\Bigg)\frac{\Pi(k^2)}{k^2}
=\frac{1}{k^2}\big(1-\Pi(k^2)\big)\Bigg[-g_{\mu\nu}-\frac{k_\mu k^\nu\Pi(k^2)}{1-\Pi(k^2)}\Bigg].\end{align}$$
Iff $\Pi(k^2)<<1$
$$\begin{align}
D'_{\mu\nu}(k)&=\frac{1}{k^2[1+\Pi(k^2)]}\Bigg(-g_{\mu\nu}-\frac{k_\mu k_\nu}{k^2}\Pi(k^2)\Bigg)\\&=\frac{-g_{\mu\nu}}{k^2[1+\Pi(k^2)]} + \text{gauge terms}.   
\end{align}\tag{9.124}$$

But in fact, $\Pi(k^2)>>1$ because $$\Pi(k^2)=\frac{e^2}{6\pi^2\epsilon}+\frac{e^2k^2}{60\pi^2m^2}+\ldots$$, and this $\epsilon$ is very small in fact, its magnitude is almost equal to zero. So we can't use power series in fact, Then how would we say Ryder's derivation is correct??

Comment: Try a value. Maybe ten terms on your calculator for $x=2$. Do you think that looks like it's converging? (Of course, this is not a rigorous method to show convergence or divergence, just an illustration to help you).

Comment: The right side diverges if $x>1$

Comment: My motivation for this post is a question that asked by me in physics stalk exchange, please check this link for that question,  https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/575050/is-ryder-correct?noredirect=1#comment1296482_575050

Comment: is this  "https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/575050/is-ryder-correct?noredirect=1#comment1296482_575050"  a mathematical blunder, what's your views as mathematicians? Please check the answer of this question that given by a user in Physics stalk exchange,he explains it using formal power series...

Comment: In the ring $K[[x]]$ of formal power series in the indeterminate $x$ (where $K$ is an arbitrary field), we have $$(1 - x)\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} x^k = 1\,,$$ in other words $(1-x)$ is invertible in $K[[x]]$ and $(1-x)^{-1} = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} x^k$. But if you plug in a real or complex number for $x$, the series converges only if $\lvert x\rvert < 1$.

Comment: Your explanations are very messy. For instance "this $\epsilon\to0$ in the real problem" does not make much sense when there is no $\epsilon$. Sorry, I can't help further.

Comment: again edited@Yves Daoust

Answer (score 2):

As a *series of real numbers*, $(1-x)^{-1}=1+x+x^2+x^3+\ldots$ holds for $|x|\lt 1$. (For $|x|\ge 1$, the RHS diverges.)

As a *formal power series* (see: [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series)), $1-x\in\mathbb R[[x]]$ is invertible, and its inverse is $1+x+x^2+x^3+\ldots$ because $(1-x)(1+x+x^2+\ldots)=1$ in $\mathbb R[[x]]$. Note in this context $x$ is purely a symbol and the multiplication is formal, and does not involve substitution of $x$ with any value.

So, the answer here is that Mathematics has *both* of those tools for Physics' disposal,  I guess the question is "which one makes physical sense". Apparently using formal power series "works" here - gives results that agree with the experiment.

Comment: I think you give the closest answer .. still have some doubts 1)$(1-x)(1+x+x^2+\ldots)=1$ , how you argue this? More precisely how you argue inverse of $1-x$ is $1+x+x^2+x^3+\dots$?@Stinking Bishop

Comment: The rule of multiplication in $\mathbb R[[x]]$ is: $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n\times\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_nx^n:=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (a_0b_n+a_1b_{n-1}+\ldots+a_nb_0)x^n$. Apply it to your case and you will see that all the coefficients except for the leading constant $1$ will cancel out.

Comment: @QFTaddict (Forgot to say: you *first* argue that the product of those two formal series is $1$, *then* you argue that they are inverses of each other - not the other way round.)

Answer (score 0):

No; since each term on the RHS is increasing by a factor of $x$, if $\left| x\right|>1$, then $$\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=\pm \infty,$$ so the series diverges.

Another way to think about it is that since $\left| a_n \right|$ is monotonically increasing, each term "cancels out" the effect of the last one and makes the magnitude grow in either the positive or negative direction. Since the series is infinite, this growth in magnitude never stops, so the series diverges.

Comment: Can you please check this link and also its answer@Pendronator

Answer (score 0):

No, with $|x|\ge1$, the general term does not tend to $0$ and the series diverges.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/575050/is-ryder-correct?noredirect=1#comment1296482_575050, Can you please check this link...@Yves Daoust

Comment: @QFTaddict: what for ? There is no connection with your question.

Comment: No there is a connection $x=\Pi(k^2)$  and also this $\Pi(k^2)$ is  greater than one, with this base try to read the same question one more time, please@ Yves Daoust

Comment: @QFTaddict: I confirm that there is no connection. The series diverges.

Comment: I edited the post, please help me@Yves Daoust